# Demo, promo, trial, prototype, 1st releases

Tags: ubuntu-edge

How do I voluneer to test products like The Edge, phablets, software, etc? Where do I sign up for an open invitation for anything new including hardware?

Answer (score 2):

There's no universal place. It helps if you are a sysadmin, a blogger, web columnist, or all of the above. Write reviews of new gear and software, post them in your blog, then seek an invite to write for Examiner.com or other, similar tech-oriented sites.

I'd also suggest creating a technically oriented blog and post hardware reviews there, as well as reviewing new distros and then posting them at http://distrowatch.org . As an example, I find no review yet of the Gnome 3 version of Ubuntu 13.10 at http://distrowatch.org/table.php?distribution=ubuntugnome and there's a place to start.

Once you have a portfolio of reviews, then you can start contacting folks to say 'You know, if I had your stuff, I'd do a respectable job of reviewing it.'

Suggestions for sharpening your tech writing tools:

http://www.chrisbrogan.com/

http://www.wikihow.com/Be-a-Good-Writer

http://www.cyberjournalist.net/news/000118.php

http://www.copyblogger.com/the-first-rule-of-copyblogger

http://www.chrisbrogan.com/finding-hidden-communities/

Once you get your foot in the door, your rep will grow, and you will have as much gear as [Jerry Pournelle](http://www.jerrypournelle.com/jerrypournelle.c/chaosmanor/) (who has been tech reviewing since CP/M was Hot Stuff).

Where are you located? I ask, for if you are in Portland Metro, HP's Deskjet division is in frequent need of beta testers, and I can dig up an invite. (I am NOT an HP employee nor associated with them).